# AWS Lambda NodeJS import returns null module, but only in AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, apollo-server

### UPDATED

I am getting the following error when trying to invoke my Lambda function

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "e is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: e is not a function",
    "    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:88355)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

I have tracked this down to the reference to DB (see last few lines of schema.js DB should be imported at the top of schema.js

```
const { DB } = require('./db.js')
```

Indeed, when I try the same code on my local computer, there is no issue.

Does this have to do with some subtle ways how Lambda Functions (LF) are frozen for re-use in AWS? Where should I be initializing the DB connection in a LF?

I tried merging db.js into schema.js (no import) and I still get the same error. 
I have checked the zip file that serverless loaded and it looks fine (node_modules and mine).

This is very hard to debug. So any tips in that direction would help.

---

### server.js

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')
const { ApolloServer: ApolloServerLambda } = require('apollo-server-lambda')
const { typeDefs, resolvers, connect } = require('./schema.js')

// The ApolloServer constructor requires two parameters: your schema
// definition and your set of resolvers.

async function setup(where) {
  if (where == 'local') {
    const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
    let { url } = await server.listen()
    console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`)
  } else {
    const server = new ApolloServerLambda({ 
      typeDefs, 
      resolvers,
      playground: true,
      introspection: true,
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true,
      },
      context: ({ event, context }) => (
        {
          headers: event.headers,
          functionName: context.functionName,
          event,
          context
        })
    })
    exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler()
  }
}

let location = (process.env.USERNAME == 'ysg4206') ? 'local' : 'aws'
connect(location, setup)
```

---

### schema.js

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')
const { GraphQLDateTime } = require('graphql-iso-date')
const { DB } = require('./db.js')

exports.typeDefs = gql`
  scalar DateTime

  type User {
    id: Int
    "English First Name"
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    addressNumber: Int
    streetName: String
    city: String
    email: String
    createdAt: DateTime
    updatedAt: DateTime
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User]
    findUser(firstName: String): User
    hello(reply: String): String
  }

  type Mutation {
    addUser(user: UserType): User!
  }

  type Subscription {
    newUser: User!
  }
`

exports.resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: () => DB.findAll(),
    findUser: async (_, { firstName }) => {
      let who = await DB.findFirst(firstName)
      return who
    },
    hello: (_, { reply }, context, info) => {
      console.log(`hello with reply ${reply}`)
      console.log(`context : ${JSON.stringify(context)}`)
      console.log(`info : ${JSON.stringify(info)}`)
      return reply
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    addUser: async (_, args) => {
      let who = await DB.addUser(args.user)
      return who
    }
  }
}

exports.connect = async (where, setup) => {
  console.log(`DB: ${DB}')    // BUG DB is returning null
  await DB.dbSetup(where)             //BUG these lines cause Lambda to fail
  await DB.populate()                 //BUG these lines cause Lambda to fail
  let users = await DB.findAll()      //BUG these lines cause Lambda to fail
  console.log(users)                  //BUG these lines cause Lambda to fail
  await setup(where)
}
```

---

### db.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const { userData } = require('./userData')

const localHost = {
    db: 'm3_db',
    host: 'localhost',
    pass: 'xxxx'
}
const awsHost = {
    db: 'mapollodb3_db',
    host: 'apollodb.cxeokcheapqj.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    pass: 'xxxx'
}

class DB {

    async dbSetup(where) {
        let host = (where == "local") ? localHost : awsHost
        this.db = new Sequelize(host.db, 'postgres', host.pass, {
            host: host.host,
            dialect: 'postgres',
            logging: false,
            pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                idle: 20000,
                handleDisconnects: true
            },
            dialectOptions: {
                requestTimeout: 100000
            },
            define: {
                freezeTableName: true
            }
        })
        this.User = this.db.define('users', {
            firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
            lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
            addressNumber: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            streetName: Sequelize.STRING,
            city: Sequelize.STRING,
            email: Sequelize.STRING,
        })
        try {
            await this.db.authenticate()
            console.log('Connected to DB')
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Unable to connect to DB', err)
        }
    }

    async select(id) {
        let who = await this.User.findAll({ where: { id: id } })
        return who.get({ plain: true })
    }

    async findFirst(name) {
        let me = await this.User.findAll({ where: { firstName: name } })
        return me[0].get({ plain: true })
    }

    async addUser(user) {
        let me = await this.User.create(user)
        return me.get({ plain: true })
    }

    async  populate() {
        await this.db.sync({ force: true })
        try {
            await this.User.bulkCreate(userData, { validate: true })
            console.log('users created');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('failed to create users')
            console.error(err)
        } finally {
        }
    }

    async findAll() {
        let users = await this.User.findAll({ raw: true })
        return users
    }

    async close() {
        this.db.close()
    }
}

exports.DB = new DB()
```

---

### serverless.yml

```
service: apollo-lambda
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  runtime: nodejs10.x
#  cfnRole: arn:aws:iam::237632220688:role/lambda-role
functions:
  graphql:
    # this is formatted as <FILENAME>.<HANDLER>
    handler: server.graphqlHandler
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - sg-a1e6f4c3
      subnetIds:
        - subnet-4a2a7830
        - subnet-1469d358
        - subnet-53b45038
    events:
    - http:
        path: graphql
        method: post
        cors: true
    - http:
        path: graphql
        method: get
        cors: true
```

folder structure of zip

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Are you using a bundler? Or, a deployment tool? Have you checked in the AWS Lambda console if all files are present?

Comment: I only use the serverless.com framework which creates a zip. Code is developed in vscode and deployed by serverless

Comment: The error message shown comes from the console

Comment: Inspect the contents of that zip file that serverless packages for you. Another way of checking is to go to the AWS Lambda console as stated in my first comment. You might be missing some files.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you post your `serverless.yml`.

Comment: Since it is a zip, no way to check in console. But I did download the zip and it has the latest changes. I also added the serverless.yml

Comment: Can you try with `const  DB  = require('./db.js'); ` ?

Comment: Can you post the file structure of what's inside the zip?

Comment: Top level of folder now shown. All node_modules match in the subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It is a bit embarrassing. But I post it in case others need this.

I was trying to connect to the DB as part of the initialization of the lambda app. Hoping that when the cold start or warm start happened, the variable with DB would be already holding the connection.

That is anti-pattern.

With apollo one has to reconnect to the DB on each request. that is in the resolver for the GraphQL one has to reconnect to the DB and then close it so that AWS can see there are no open connections and then close the Lambda function.

What threw me was this worked fine when running as ApolloServer and connecting to a local DB.

Answer (score 0):

When AWS Lambda imports your file, the export isn't available yet. That's why it complains that your handler is not a function (because it is actually `undefined` at that time it is being imported).

Here are a couple of suggested solutions:

**1. Use only `apollo-server-lambda` and use [`serverless-offline`](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) for local development.** This way your handler code is exactly the same as what you have in Lambda.

```
const { ApolloServer: ApolloServerLambda } = require("apollo-server-lambda");
const { typeDefs, resolvers, connect } = require("./schema.js");

const server = new ApolloServerLambda({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: true,
  introspection: true,
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true
  },
  context: ({ event, context }) => ({
    headers: event.headers,
    functionName: context.functionName,
    event,
    context
  })
});

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

**2. Use `apollo-server-lambda` in your Lambda but use `apollo-server` in another file (e.g. local.js).**. Then, you just use `node local.js` for local development. No need for that `process.env.USERNAME` check that you do at the end.

Comment: No, tried this and it was not the issue. I still got the same error when only using the lambda version. I found my problem and it is in the answer.